# Understanding an application of Riemann-Roch in an article

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I saw the following in an article:

Let $C$ be an irreducible smooth projective curve over an algebraically closed field $K$ and let $g$ be its genus.
By Riemann-Roch, if N is large enough for every line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $C$ of degree $\leq g+1$, $\mathcal{O}(N)|_C\otimes\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ is generated by its global sections. It follows that, for $N$ large enough any function on $C$ with at most $g+1$ poles is the quotient of two homogeneous polynomials of degree $N$.

Why is this true? What is the connection two the fact that it is generated by global sections?

Comment: I've fixed it. I mean the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(N)$ of the projective space restricted to the curve C.